# Partial differentiation of action function

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-calculus, discrete, functional-derivatives

I'm trying to understand the principle of least action, and the author of the book I'm reading is presenting of derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation.

The author picks an arbitrary position $x_8$ and attempts to minimize the action function for that point.

He makes these substitutions and uses discrete time:

$$x'=\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\Delta t}$$

$$x=\frac{x_{n}+x_{n+1}}{2}.$$

Starting from this:

$$A=L(\frac{x_9-x_8}{\Delta t},\frac{x_8+x_9}{2})\Delta t+L(\frac{x_8-x_7}{\Delta t},\frac{x_7+x_8}{2})\Delta t.$$

I can't figure out how he gets the right side from differentiating by $x_8$:

$$\frac{∂A}{∂x_8}=\left(-\frac{∂L}{∂x'}\Biggr|_{n=9}+\frac{∂L}{∂x'}\Biggr|_{n=8}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{∂L}{∂x}\Biggr|_{n=8}+\frac{∂L}{∂x}\Biggr|_{n=9}\right)\Delta t.$$

Comment: What do you get when *you* differentiate that expression?  It seems like a fairly straightforward application of the chain rule to me.

Comment: You're right. I just forgot about the chain rule for partial differentiation, it's been a while. Using it I get the same thing as the author.

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496681/11127

Comment: I'm voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.